# Lutris broke, 1 week down the rabbit hole, pip refuses to run

Tags: package-management, 19.10, pip

My lutris install broke, and after a week down that rabbithole of errors, i have been halted.

lutris spits out this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lutris", line 34, in <module>
    from lutris.gui.application import Application
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/gui/application.py", line 34, in <module>
    from lutris.game import Game
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/game.py", line 11, in <module>
    from lutris import runtime
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/runtime.py", line 7, in <module>
    from lutris.util import http, jobs, system
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/http.py", line 3, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 20, in <module>
    from urllib.error import URLError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lutris", line 34, in <module>
    from lutris.gui.application import Application
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/gui/application.py", line 34, in <module>
    from lutris.game import Game
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/game.py", line 11, in <module>
    from lutris import runtime
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/runtime.py", line 7, in <module>
    from lutris.util import http, jobs, system
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lutris/util/http.py", line 3, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib'
```

So i turned to pip,and this happened.
No matter what i put in, pip always spits out this error messsage, i have tried to solve this problem for 2 days now, and i have no clue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: No module named urllib3.exceptions
```

I do not know what to do, i dont know who to ask, so i'm putting it here.
I am on 19.10 with the default DM, DE, WM and kernel.

Comment: Have you made ANY changes to Python or Python3? Looks like you need to reinstall  your stdlib.

Comment: i have, i apt purged pip then deleted all traces of it in /usr/local and /usr/bin/

Comment: also, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: First, pick a Python version. 2 or 3. Pick one and stick to it. (Hint: 2 is a bad choice - it's past End of Life).Stop using the other.

Comment: Next, look at your error messages: `No module named 'urllib'` A Google Search for `python3 urllib ubuntu` leads to the package `python3-urllib3`. Install it, and see if that fixes the error message.

Comment: I tried this, and it said it was already installed. i reinstalled it with `sudo apt reinstall python3-urllib3` and then ran lutris. I got the exact same error message.